# How to terminate cin>> input with specific word/letter/number/etc

Tags: c++, string, io, inputstream, formatted-input

How to use cin>> again after it fails or how to exit
 `while(cin>>some_string>>some_int)` legitimately so that cin>> can be used again?

Exercise goes something like this : Fill 2 vectors (1 string and 1 int) with name and age,
terminate input by the line "no more", ask for a name for which the program need to output corresponding age ( or "name not found"). My problem is with cin>> : when i enter "no more" any attept of using cin>> again is fail.

code:

```
{
vector<string>name_s;
vector<int>age_s;
int age = 0,checker=0;
string name;
while( cin>>name>>age)         //input of name and age
{
    name_s.push_back(name);    //filling vectors 
    age_s.push_back(age);
}
string name_check;
cout<<"\nEnter a name you want to check : ";
cin>>name_check;
for(int i =0;i<name_s.size();++i)
    {
        if(name==name_s[i])
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<name_check<<", "<<age_s[i]<<"\n";
            ++checker;
        }
    }
if(checker<1)
    cout<<"\nName not found.\n";
system("PAUSE");
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"terminate input by the line `"no more"`"*

Yould could read the input by lines, not by words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
...
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && line != "no more") {
    if (line.empty()) ; // TODO: line might be empty

    std::istringstream is(line);
    std::string name;
    int age;
    if (is >> name && is >> age) { /* TODO: store new data */ }
}
```

If you want to take care of situation when there are additional characters after this `no more` then you might use [`line.substr(0,7) != "no more"`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and if you just want to find out if `no more` is within the line, not necessarily at the beginning, you can do: `line.find("no more") != std::string::npos`

Comment: i knew i needed to point this out : please no advanced stuff, im doing a book from Bjarne Stoustrup c++ and so far i learned functions, loops and vectors. So getline .empty() istringstream is() is SF to me. I can use it but i dont see the point if you know what i mean. Thanks

Comment: @user3446166: Well if you are working with `>>` on `std::cin` then `std::getline` for reading whole string is perfectly reasonable alternative. Instead of `line.empty()` you can do `line == ""` and instead of `istringstream` you can parse this line manually.

Comment: in exercise it goes like this ( i quote) : " Terminate the input by the line No more ("more" will make the attempt to read another integer fail). " Even if i use getline its not what im asked to do ( i think).

Comment: Can i use string for name AND age input and check it with if(condition) break; ?

Comment: apparently you were right, while (cin>>name>>age && name!="NoName") is the solution